# Can you give some information for rothe method

Tags: pde, finite-difference, numerical-analysis, reference-request, method-of-lines

I want to learn a numerical method for PDEs other than finite difference method. After some research on internet i have found Rothe method and it looks interesting to me. Unfortunately, i couldn't find a good book/ notes for starting. Can you suggest me a book to study? What is prerequisites/corequisites for the Rothe method?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Rothe's method is semidiscretization in time before space (a transpose of the more common "method of lines").  That choice is orthogonal to the discretization scheme (finite difference/volume/element).  I suggest reading about finite volume methods if you are interested in hyperbolic problems (wave propagation and similar) or finite elements if you are interested in elliptic or parabolic problems.

Comment: @Jed Brown first of all  thanks for answering my question. Actually i dont understand the relation between rothe method and finite element method. Can you explain that relation much more ? i will be grateful if you could.

Comment: FD is a space or time discretization.  The distinction between Rothe vs Method of Lines is only whether you discretize in time-then-space or space-then-time.  You said you want to go beyond FD, so read up on FV or FE.  This is orthogonal to using Rothe vs Method of Lines.  (I prefer MoL because I think it is much better at enabling software reuse.)

Comment: Related: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/pde-discretization-with-the-method-of-rothe-and-the-method-of-lines-modular-imp

Comment: Ok @Jed Brown  thank you so much. can you suggest me a good introductory book for FEMs and a basic illustration  of MoL

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/modern-resources-for-learning-fem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 30 minute introduction that explains the difference between the method of lines and the Rothe method: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bangerth/videos.676.26.html